# WordPress post type "event" query string fix?

Tags: query

What am I doing wrong in this query? I want to select events from a custom post type called events and order by the event date and only show ones after the current date. It doesn't seem to work...

```
$querystr = "

SELECT $wpdb->posts.* 
FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'wpcf-start-date'
AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value >= CURDATE() 
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'events'
ORDER BY $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value ASC

";
```

Comment: In what format are date values stored?

Comment: The input format is Month dd, yyyy

Comment: Why aren't you using `WP_QUERY`?

Answer (score 1):

Your date format is wrong, MySQL date format is `yyyy-mm-dd`. Once you get that fixed, see [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)'s `meta_query`, no need for raw SQL in this case.